# View for backed-up transaction logs

Tags: sql-server, backup

Can someone please let me know the view name to see all backed-up transaction logs, their sizes in SQLServer ?

In Oracle, it is `v$archived_logs`. Similar to this, I want to know the view for sqlserver.

Answer (score 3):

You can view the backup history by using the tables in msdb, backupset and backupmediafamily.  I use this query to see the history of all backups for specific databases.

Note that if you backup to multiple files, each file will appear on it's own line.

```
SELECT MF.physical_device_name AS BackupFilePath
        , BackupType = CASE WHEN BS.[type] = 'D' THEN 1
                            WHEN BS.[type] = 'L' THEN 2
                            WHEN BS.[type] = 'I' THEN 5
                            ELSE NULL
                            END
        , BackupType_Desc = CASE WHEN BS.[type] = 'D' THEN 'FULL'
                            WHEN BS.[type] = 'L' THEN 'LOG'
                            WHEN BS.[type] = 'I' THEN 'DIFF'
                            ELSE NULL
                            END
        , BS.position AS Position
        , BS.[database_name] AS DatabaseName
        , BS.first_lsn AS FirstLSN
        , BS.last_lsn AS LastLSN
        , BS.checkpoint_lsn AS CheckPointLSN
        , BS.database_backup_lsn AS DatabaseBackupLSN
        , BS.backup_start_date 
        , BS.backup_finish_date
        , DATEDIFF(MINUTE, BS.backup_start_date, BS.backup_finish_date) AS BackupDuration_Min
        , ROUND(BS.backup_size/1024.0/1024.0, 3) AS BackupSize_MB
        , ROUND(BS.compressed_backup_size/1024.0/1024.0, 3) AS BackupSizeComprssed_MB
    FROM msdb.dbo.backupset AS BS
        LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily AS MF ON MF.media_set_id = BS.media_set_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's the [msdb.dbo.backupset](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186299(v=sql.110).aspx) table - that might be a starting point for you.

My usual query for looking into this sort of thing is:

```
SELECT b.database_name,
    b.server_name,
    b.backup_start_date,
    b.backup_finish_date,
    b.type,
    b.backup_size,
    b.compressed_backup_size
FROM msdb.dbo.backupset AS b
ORDER BY b.database_name,
    b.type,
    b.backup_start_date;
```